# How to determine which of the 6 columns of this matrix are not linearly independent when combing with the rest?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

I currently have a matrix $G$ with $6$ columns from a simulation that looks like:

$$\begin{bmatrix}{}
1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ 
  0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.5 & -0.5 \\ 
  0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & -0.5 & 0.5 \\ 
  0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\ 
  0.0 & 0.5 & -0.5 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 \\ 
  0.0 & -0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is basically a correlation matrix I have which was constructed from a model matrix in which I will use in a least squares estimation. I was told in a talk that the dimension of this above correlation matrix is $5$, since one of above columns can be removed to create a matrix that has linearly independent columns. My question is, is there an easy to see which one it is above without an algorithm? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $r_i $ defines the $i^{th}$ row in the matrix above, then you will have $r_3-r_2+r_5 = r_6$, so you can eliminate one of those rows.

In other words, (since your matrix is symmetric), you can elimante one of the $\{2,3,5,6\}$ colomns